How do I fix this PCIe Bus Error?
I don't know how to fix the following PCIeBus Error code, it shows up as the following:
severity=Correctible,
type=Physical Layer,
(Transmitter ID) device {10ec:8136}
error status /mask=00001081/00006000

This is on Ubuntu 24.04.

This is a bug for RTL810xE that was first reported on Ubuntu 23.04 and persists
Please see Launchpad Bugs, specifically the last 2 entries. Make sure to enter your info in This bug affects 2 people. Does this bug affect you? to receive notifications for any status changes and also increase the heat (importance) of the bug so that it gets dealt with sooner.
At the moment the workaround is modify GRUB's default parameters by adding pci=noaer (see detailed steps below) as suggested in https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218784#c1, although that doesn't solve the underlying problem. From https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html:

noaer           [PCIE] If the PCIEAER kernel config parameter is
                enabled, this kernel boot option can be used to
                disable the use of PCIE advanced error reporting.


If that doesn't work you may try pcie_aspm-off or pci=nomsi.
To add the parameter to GRUB if you are unable to boot into Ubuntu:

Start your system and wait for the GRUB menu to show up (if you don't see a GRUB menu, press and hold the Left Shift key right after starting the system).

Now highlight the kernel you want to use, and press the e key. You should be able to see and edit the commands associated with the highlighted kernel.

Go down to the line starting with linux and add the parameter pci=noaer at the end.

Now press Ctrl+x to boot.


Note that the above procedure is temporary, but will allow you to boot into Ubuntu. To add the parameter permanently, follow these steps after booting to Ubuntu:

From a terminal (or after pressing Alt+F2) run:
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub

(or use sudo nano if gksudo or gedit are not available) and enter your password.

Find the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and append pci=noaer at the end:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"


Save the file and close the editor.

Finally, start a terminal and run the following command to update GRUB's configuration file (you probably need to enter your password):
sudo update-grub



Source: @htorque's answer in How do I add a kernel boot parameter?

this all worked for me except I ended up having to use pci-nomsi

You should enroll in that bug report since the real problem is still there.

@DonNoyes If this answer has solved your issue please 'Accept' the answer by clicking on the tick or check mark, this will indicate to other users that this is a successful answer that may help them as well...
